# Boundedness of a value

Tags: inequality

Is there any difference between assuming:

1) $f(x) \lt C$ for some finite constant $C$

and

2) $f(x) \leq C$ for some finite constant $C$?

Far more frequently you would write the former, so would I, but if the $C$ is undefined in any way and the only thing that matters is that it is finite - then what's the difference, technically? Obviously if $f(x) \leq C$ then there exists $\tilde C = C + 1$ for which $f(x) \lt \tilde C$, well you know. I understand that the question itself may be considered quite stupid, but it got stuck in my head. I had some thoughts on it but they're long since forgotten.

Comment: Usually there is a context to the constant $C$, it's not just any constant, but it's a specific constant bounding $f$, and makes difference if $f$ may or not reach $C$.

Comment: Also note that $f(x)\leq C_0\implies f(x)<C_1$ for some (infinite) known $C_1$, as you observed. But $f(x)<C_0\implies f(x) \leq C_1$ for some known $C_1$ is not necessarily true. You are able do construct $C_1$ in the first case, but not in the second.

Comment: @Integral: What? If $f(x)<C_0$ then $f(x)\le C_0$, so we can just take $C_1=C_0$.

Comment: Pay attention at the logic you are using. When you say "If $f(x)<C_0$ then $f(x)\leq C_0$ " you are in fact saying "if $f(x)<C_0$ then $f(x)<C_0$ or $f(x)=C_0$". The second statement ( $f(x)=C_0$ ) is false, but the "or" connective makes the whole statement "$f(x)<C_0$ or $f(x)=C_0$" be true. I could say "if $f(x)<C_0$ then $f(x)<C_0$ or ANYTHING" and this still would be true.

Comment: In short, yes you can write $C_0=C_1$ and use this argument, but it's a void argument that goes to nowhere. The point, obviously, is to construct $C_1\neq C_0$, what is possible in the case $f(x)\leq C_0$.

Comment: You are talking about the case where we need to stress that the function indeed takes the value $C_0$ every now and then, but is it really the point of boundedness? We're not looking for a supremum, we just want to be safe when saying "it's not greater" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both conditions mean that $f$ is bounded from above. As said in the comments, if $f(x)<C$ for all $x$ then of course also $f(x)\le C$ for all $x$. And if $f(x)\le C$ for all $x$ then for example $f(x)<C':=C+1$ for all $x$.
If you let $C=\sup f(x)$, you clearly only get $\le$. And if you want to use the expression $\frac1{C-f(x)}$ somewhere, you better use the definition with $<$.  So both variants have their advantages.

There are many similar instances of moot distinctions, for example defining $a_n\to a$ as $\forall\epsilon>0\colon \exists N\in\mathbb N\colon \forall n>N\colon |a_n-a|<\epsilon$ or $\forall\epsilon>0\colon \exists N\in\mathbb N\colon \forall n\ge N\colon |a_n-a|\le\epsilon$ doesn't really matter. But beware of starting with $\forall \epsilon\ge0$, and that may be one reason why $<$ throughout is widely preferred over $\le$.

In summary, you are free to use either definitions of "bounded from above", but should preferably use and show the exact property used in the explicit definition in your textbook.